# JOIN Alternative to SELECT Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

I am trying to convert a SELECT subquery to a JOIN statement, so it works on Netezza. I was originally working on a Oracle database where the following query worked fine, but Netezza does not support subqueries in the SELECT statements. I managed to get the SELECT subquery into an ON statement, but Netezza doesn't support that either.

My query is trying to find the the daily revenue of individual product sales by looking up the daily quantity sold and the historical price for that date.

Any suggestions on how to decompose this statement into something Netezza would accept? I am also interested to know if any restructuring of my query would boost its efficiency.

My original Oracle SQL query:

```
Select
    SALES.DATE,
    SALES.PRODUCT,
    SALES.QUANTITY,
    (
        Select PRICE
        from
        (
            Select PRODUCT_ID, PRICE, max(EFF_DATE) as EFF_DATE
            from HIST_PRICING
            Where
                PRODUCT_ID = SALES.PRODUCT and
                SALES.DATE > EFF_DATE
            GROUP BY
                PRODUCT_ID, PRICE
        )
    ) as PRICE,
    (SALES.QUANTITY * PRICE) as REVENUE
FROM SALES_RECORDS SALES
;
```

Moved subquery to JOIN ON statement:

```
SELECT
    SALES.DATE,
    SALES.PRODUCT,
    SALES.QUANTITY,
    H.PRICE,
    (SALES.QUANTITY * H.PRICE) as REVENUE
FROM SALES_RECORDS SALES
LEFT JOIN HIST_PRICING H ON
    SALES.PRODUCT = H.PRODUCT and
    SALES.DATE =
        (
            Select MAX(EFF_DATE) AS MOST_RECENT
            FROM HIST_PRICING
            WHERE SALES.PRODUCT = HIST_PRICING.PRODUCT
              AND EFF_DATE <= SALES.DATE
            GROUP BY SALES.PRODUCT
        )
```

For reference, here is a simplified example of what my table data looks like.

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║           SALES_RECORDS             ║
╠═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╣
║   DATE    ║ PRODUCT ║ QUANTITY_SOLD ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1/1/2015  ║ SHOES   ║           500 ║
║ 2/5/2015  ║ SHOES   ║          1200 ║
║ 3/7/2015  ║ TOYS    ║           600 ║
║ 3/9/2015  ║ SHOES   ║           100 ║
║ 5/10/2015 ║ HATS    ║           400 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╝
╔══════════════════════════════╗
║          HIST_PRICING        ║
╠═══════════╦═════════╦════════╣
║ EFF_DATE  ║ PRODUCT ║  PRICE ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ 1/1/2015  ║ SHOES   ║ $50    ║
║ 1/1/2015  ║ TOYS    ║ $10    ║
║ 1/1/2015  ║ HATS    ║ $20    ║
║ 2/15/2015 ║ SHOES   ║ $45    ║
║ 2/15/2015 ║ HATS    ║ $15    ║
║ 3/1/2015  ║ HATS    ║ $20    ║
║ 5/1/2015  ║ TOYS    ║ $15    ║
║ 8/1/2015  ║ SHOES   ║ $55    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use `LEFT JOIN`. Doe all of your products exist on the `HIST_PRICING` table? also, you don't need to group by in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do an inline view in the `FROM` clause... or, if you have DBA privileges to `CREATE VIEW`, then you can do this:

```
Select
    SALES."DATE",
    SALES.PRODUCT,
    SALES.QUANTITY,
    PRICES.PRICE,
    (SALES.QUANTITY * PRICES.PRICE) as REVENUE
FROM SALES_RECORDS SALES LEFT JOIN
        (
            Select PRODUCT_ID, PRICE, max(EFF_DATE) as EFF_DATE
            from HIST_PRICING
            GROUP BY
                PRODUCT_ID, PRICE
        ) PRICES ON PRICES.PRODUCT_ID = SALES.PRODUCT AND PRICES.EFF_DATE <= SALES."DATE"
;
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
Select
    SALES."DATE",
    SALES.PRODUCT,
    SALES.QUANTITY,
    PRICES.PRICE,
    (SALES.QUANTITY * PRICES.PRICE) as REVENUE
FROM SALES_RECORDS SALES LEFT JOIN HIST_PRICING PRICES ON PRICES.PRODUCT_ID = SALES.PRODUCT AND PRICES.EFF_DATE <= SALES."DATE"
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'later price for product prior to sales date'
                   FROM   hist_pricing p2
                   WHERE  p2.product_id = prices.product_id
                   AND    p2.eff_date <= sales."DATE"
                   -- NOTE: too simple - assumes you never have two prices for the same product on the same date.  
                   -- If that can happen, you need to adjust the logic below to include a tie-breaker.
                   AND    p2.eff_date > prices.eff_date )
;
```

Oracle has all sorts of ways to improve upon both of those (e.g., `MAX() KEEP`).  But these are two fairly vanilla SQL ways to re-express your original SQL and get rid of the scalar subquery.

Answer (score 0):

For the task *to find the the daily revenue of individual product sales by looking up the daily quantity sold and the historical price for that date* I'd sugest this approach:

In the first step define (extend) the product price validity interval.
This is done with a simple analytic function (alternative a self join if not supported in Netezza).

```
select PRODUCT_ID, EFF_DATE eff_date_from, 
nvl(lead(EFF_DATE-1) over (partition by product_id order by EFF_DATE),to_date('1/1/2100','mm/dd/yyyy')) eff_date_to,
PRICE from HIST_PRICING order by PRODUCT_ID, EFF_DATE
```

yielding a price table with PRICE and valid FROM - valid TO dates.
Note that both dates are inclusive (done with -1 day) and the last TO date is in far future, which alloves simple filter using BETWEEN.

*Caution - this works only for DATEs (without a time component). If the validity column contains time too, you subtract only the smallest unit, e.g  1 second.*

```
PRODUCT_ID EFF_DATE_FROM       EFF_DATE_TO              PRICE
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
HATS       01.01.2015 00:00:00 14.02.2015 00:00:00         20 
HATS       15.02.2015 00:00:00 28.02.2015 00:00:00         15 
HATS       01.03.2015 00:00:00 01.01.2100 00:00:00         20 
SHOES      01.01.2015 00:00:00 14.02.2015 00:00:00         50 
SHOES      15.02.2015 00:00:00 31.07.2015 00:00:00         45 
SHOES      01.08.2015 00:00:00 01.01.2100 00:00:00         55 
TOYS       01.01.2015 00:00:00 30.04.2015 00:00:00         10 
TOYS       01.05.2015 00:00:00 01.01.2100 00:00:00         15
```

The query is a simple join (use outer join with some dummy price if the history table could be incomplete) on product and constraining theh price validity with the sales_date.

```
Select
    SALES."DATE",
    SALES.PRODUCT_ID,
    SALES.QUANTITY,
    (SALES.QUANTITY * PRICE) as REVENUE,
    PRICE
from  SALES_RECORDS  SALES
join 
(  
select PRODUCT_ID, EFF_DATE eff_date_from, 
nvl(lead(EFF_DATE-1) over (partition by product_id order by EFF_DATE),to_date('1/1/2100','mm/dd/yyyy')) eff_date_to,
PRICE from HIST_PRICING order by PRODUCT_ID, EFF_DATE
) DAILY_PRICE
on SALES.PRODUCT_ID = DAILY_PRICE.PRODUCT_ID and
 SALES."DATE" BETWEEN DAILY_PRICE.eff_date_from and DAILY_PRICE.eff_date_to
;
```